# How can you use a :before pseudo class with a :not pseudo class together?

Tags: css

Is it possible to use a `before` pseudo class and attach a `not` pseudo class?

For example, given a simple list of items, I'm adding a "lightgray" dot behind each list item name:

```
// HTML:

<ul>
  <li>Ace</li>
  <li class="notme">Bay</li>
  <li>Cat</li>
</ul>


// CSS:

li {
  padding: 10px;
  color: green;
}

li::before {
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

See also the following codepen:
https://codepen.io/philipyoo/pen/KKMPOgW

What I'm trying to achieve is to continue relying on the `before` pseudo class but do not add the styles it provides for any list item with the class `notme`.

In the codepen example, "Ace" and "Cat" should continue to have the lightgray circle background, and "Bay" should not have that lightgray circle background. Is there a way to chain the `not` pseudo class to a `before` pseudo class?

Comment: just `li:not(.notme)::before`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here You have: [codepen](https://codepen.io/philipyoo/pen/KKMPOgW) - just use `li:not(.notme):before { ... }`